# データフレームで行ラベルの名前を列に追加したい

Tags: r

データフレーム

```
　　name   price 
行
１  apple   100 
２  orange  120
３  cabbage 180
```

…と言ったデータフレームがある時に行ラベルの１、２、３を列のデータとして取り込むにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

```
　　ID name   price 
行
１  1  apple   100 
２  2  orange  120
３  3  cabbage 180
```

…こんな感じになります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `df <- cbind(ID = row.names(df), df)` ですかね。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(name = c("apple", "orange", "cabbage"),
                    price = c(100, 120, 180)) %>% 
    tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "ID")
```